# find tries to access unreadable directory even though it is explicitly excluded

Tags: linux, find, gnu

This command: `find $HOME/Dev/missing \( -not -path '/home/filip/Dev/missing/.password-store' \)`

returns this:

```
/home/filip/Dev/missing
find: ‘/home/filip/Dev/missing/.password-store’: Permission denied
/home/filip/Dev/missing/data-wrangling
```

But I excluded the path that can't be read.

Is there a way to disable this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you are excluding the exact path `.password-store` itself, find is still looking to descend into it (assuming it is a directory). The `-prune` option stops snips off the search tree at this point and stops any further exploration within this path.

Try something like:

```
find $HOME/Dev/missing -path $HOME/Dev/missing/.password-store -prune -o -print
```